# BootstrapTooltip position on mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I want bootstrap tooltip with my mouse cursor. Is it possible to do that in angularjs. If not then what will be the alternative of this.

Comment: question is not clear.please elaborate

Comment: Check this out.. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

Comment: Sorry I think I does not explain it well. I need the tooltip move with the cursor, not fix with any anchor tag or other tag

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Let me explain it with example that how can you display tooltip with angularjs + Bootstrap.

**Controller:**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{ name: "item 01", tooltip: "This is item 01 tooltip!"},
                    { name: "item 02", tooltip: "This is item 02 tooltip!"}];
    console.log("MyCtrl");
}

myApp.directive('tooltip', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            $(element)
                .attr('title',scope.$eval(attrs.tooltip))
                .tooltip({placement: "right"});
        }
    }
})
```

**HTML:**
Use `tooltip` at `<a>` html tag to display tooltip.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" >
            <a rel="tooltip" tooltip="item.tooltip">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

And that's done. Please see [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/cRr9K/3/).

Comment: Sorry I think I does not explain it well. I need the tooltip move with the cursor, not fix with any anchor tag or other tag